# Prediction function in ROCR : not method in "predict" for class

Tags: r, linear-regression, roc

I'm trying to plot ROC curve with ROCR , but predict function has no method for c(double,numeric). I don't know how to transform my c(double, numeric). My code :

```
donnees$Infarctus<-as.factor(donnees$Infarctus)
set.seed(123)
index<-sample(2,nrow(Infarctus),replace=TRUE,prob=c(0.7,0.3))
train<-Infarctus[index==1,]
test<-Infarctus[index==2,]
model_logi<-glm(Infarctus~.,data=train,family="binomial")
summary(model_logi)
tidy(model_logi)
(exp(coef(model_logi)))
visreg(model_logi,"DELTA",xlab="Delta",ylab="log odds(Infarctus)")
#MARGINAL EFFECT
effects_logit_dia=margins(model_logi)
print(effects_logit_dia)
summary(effects_logit_dia)
plot(effects_logit_dia)
effects_logit_dia=summary(effects_logit_dia)
pred<-predict(model_logi,test,type="response")
head(pred)
predicted<-round(pred)
head(predicted)
head(data.frame(observed=test$Infarctus,predicted=predicted))
tab<-table(predicted,test$Infarctus)
tab
sum(diag(tab))/sum(tab)*100 
confusionMatrix(tab)
pred.rocr<-prediction(pred,test$Infarctus)
```

This is the error:

> Error in UseMethod("predict") :
> pas de méthode pour 'predict' applicable pour un objet de classe "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: What is the output of  `class(train$Infarctus)`  and `class(test$Infarctus)`? You're aware that you're doing a binomial classification right? Can you print `str(test$Infarctus)` as well?

Comment: The output of train and test infarctus is "0": no infarctus and "1":infarctus. Im aware that i m doing binomial classification, is that correct?                           
 str(test$Infarctus)
 int [1:190] 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 .

Comment: Did you actually load the RORC library using library(ROCR)? Sorry for these questions - trying to narrow down where the problem is

Comment: Yes i actually use library(ROCR), is it possible that the package "margins" is responsable of prediction dysfonction ?  when i install package , i have this message: "Attachement du package : ‘margins’The following object is masked from ‘package:ROCR’: prediction".

Comment: thank you for helping me with that information. I've posted a solution to your problem as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when you call `prediction()`, you're calling a function from another package (possibly `margins`) but you really want the `prediction()` function exported from `ROCR` package instead.

A simple fix is to include the package namespace in your function call, like the following:

```
pred <- predict(model_logi,test,type="response")
pred.rocr <- ROCR::prediction(pred,test$Infarctus)
```

### Explanation and Alternatives

> "Attachement du package : ‘margins’The following object is masked from ‘package:ROCR’: prediction"

The whole error message you see was because R was using a function that was exported from this other package. That message tells you exactly this.

This could happen with **very common** function names used by different packages, authored by different developers. For example, `filter()` is another one of those very common names, and when you want to specifically use `filter()` from let's say the `dplyr` package, then you can do `dplyr::filter()` so it knows to use this function exported from that specific package.

An alternative is to just unload the `margins()` package, if it wasn't used in the script so you don't pollute the namespace. This can be done like this:

```
detach("package:margins", unload=TRUE)
```

Just make sure this package isn't used anywhere. If you absolutely have to use `margins`, then load it in before you load the `ROCR` package, so that ROCR comes last and its functions are not masked / overwritten.

I still recommend doing `ROCR::prediction(pred,test$Infarctus)` as it is far more predictable, more easy to reason (and hence troubleshoot) with, and more explicit.